# python numpy - efficient dense matrix creation

Tags: python, indexing, matrix, numpy

I am currently writing function to generate matrices based on a input file for a transportation package.  It's an 1850x1850 matrix representing the zones in a network.  These 1850 zones are also partitioned into 10 different zone groups.  Basically I am required to assign a Time Factor (number) to each combination origin zone to destination zone.

My main loop is:

```
    for i,start in enumerate(starts):
        #Create the matrix
        mat,data = creatematrix(ID)     #1850x1850

        #Read in the time factors
        lines = picklines(range(start+1,starts+21))
        lines = [lines[i]+lines[i+1] for i in range(0,len(lines),2)]
        lines = [[float(v) for v in line] for line in lines]

        #Now Lines contains the time periods for each combination of origin to destination zone

        #Generated the matrix
        for i in xrange(10):
            for j in xrange(10):
                #Assign the time factor for each O-D pair
                I,J = PythonMatrixGroups[i,j]
                data[I,J] = lines[i,j]

        #Save matrix
        mat.raw_data = data
```

Naturally the bulk of the time is spent in the double loop.  Is this the quickest way to generated a dense matrix of this sort?  I also tried the method:

```
    PQ = PythonMatrixGroups
    output = np.sum([coo_matrix((lines[i,j]*ones(len(PQ[i][j][0])), PQ),shape=((1850,1850))])
    mat.raw_data = output.toarray()
```

But it clocked almost twice as slow

Many thanks,

Comment: i am having trouble following your code--do you initialize a NumPy array of shape 1850 x 1850 then populate it? Or you 'constructing' it by doing something like 'append' for lists (i.e., adding a row w/ each iteration)?

Comment: mat,data = createmat(ID) initializes data to be a 1850x1850 ndarray filled with 0s.  The main for loop is just filling the matrix with numbers, PythonMatrixGroups contains the I,J's of each possible O-D pair

Comment: This sort of thing would be an ideal job for cython. if you type j and i as unsigned ints you should see an improvment in performance. if you are using Ipython notebook it is really easy to do using the %%cython magic, I was surprised myself.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do it in one loop as this :

```
    #Generated the matrix
    for i in xrange(10):
        #Assign the time factor for each O-D pair
        I = PythonMatrixGroups[i]
        data[I] = lines[i]
```

But I did not test this.